# alert in event handler changing its behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

In the following snippet I have two instances of the jQueryUI [spinner](https://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/) widget. For both, I've registered a handler for the `spin` event; for the first, the current value is logged to the console, for the second, the value is alerted.

When the spin buttons are used for the first instance, everything operates as expected, and the new value is logged to the console with each click. For the second instance however, the event handler gets called continuously and many alerts (to the point of clicking the "don't allow this page to create more popups" checkbox) are created. Curiously, the value alerted starts going up by 1, then by 2, then by 3 etc. etc.

I'm seeing this behaviour on Firefox 68 on Windows 7 Pro SP1. IE11 and Edge seem to work fine, but Chrome 76 has similar behaviour although it only increments and decrements by 2. Can anyone offer a suggestion as to what might be causing this and how I can resolve it?

```js
$('#cqty1').spinner().on('spin', function (e, ui) {
  console.log('value is ' + ui.value);
});

$('#cqty2').spinner().on('spin', function (e, ui) {
  alert('value is ' + ui.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="cqty1" value="0" />
<br>
<input id="cqty2" value="0" />
```

Comment: I didn't figure out the problem but instead of `spin` you can use `spinstop` and take the value from element iteself, not from function param:
`$( "#cqty1" ).spinner().on( "spinstop", function( event, ui ) {
alert( $("#cqty1").spinner( "value" ))
} );`

Comment: When logging `console.log(e)` inside the second handler you can see that the original `mousedown` event is triggered every time I press OK in the alert prompt, with that being said I haven't found any indication that the alert function is returning anything that could cause that.

Comment: @Elias when I try that I get the "old" value (pre-spin).

Comment: @empiric yeah; it seems that for some reason clicking OK effectively re-propagates the original spin event. But why does it stop (which it does eventually)?

Comment: @Nick https://jsfiddle.net/063kyc5r/  in the fiddle the value is the correct one :(

Comment: @Elias interesting. When I run it in a code snippet in Firefox I get the old value.

Comment: @Nick Strange, for me it's working  :/  I uploaded the results [firefox](http://oi64.tinypic.com/1zyvdk9.jpg) [chrome](http://oi67.tinypic.com/2gwhv09.jpg) [edge](http://oi63.tinypic.com/x4hvk9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I believe It's a problem with the jquery spinner event. i couldn't find a way trough. I found a way around. Instead of using the "spin" event, using the "stop" event.

from: 
https://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-stop

> stop( event, ui )Type: spinstop -> Triggered after a spin.

Here is my try :
https://codepen.io/guymevents/pen/rNBMKzY

here is my codepen:

```
$( function() {
    var spinner1 = $( "#cqty1" ).spinner({
  stop: function (e, ui) {
    console.log('value is ' ,e.delegateTarget.childNodes[0].value);
  }
});


var spinner2 = $( "#cqty2" ).spinner({
  stop: function (e, ui) {
    alert('value is ' + e.delegateTarget.childNodes[0].value);
  }
});

})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd prefer not to use it if I can avoid, as I am using the `spin` event to potentially prevent the spin from occurring.